# C# Overloading operator== outside the class

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, overloading, operator-keyword

I have the following scenario:

```
    public class SomeClass { 
       // Have some other data members as well  
       public int i ; 
    } 

    public class TestClass { 

        public bool SomeFunction() { 
             SomeClass a = new SomeClass(); 
             SomeClass b = new SomeClass(); 
             if (a == b) // this is where I am getting compile error
               return true; 
             return false; 
         } 

        public static bool operator==(SomeClass a, SomeClass b) { 
             if (a.i == b.i)
               return true; 
             // compare some other members as well
             return false; 
        } 
    }
```

Is this possible to achieve in C#?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why you want do it out of class?

Comment: Because in the actual code the class, in the example above "SomeClass", is someone else's and I am trying to validate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible to override an operator from a class that is not involved in the operation.

---

You can make a class that implements `IEualityComparer<SomeClass>`, which can be used instead of the standard comparison in some cases, for example in a dictionary:

```
var x = new Dictionary<SomeClass, string>(new SomeClassEqualityComparer());
```

---

If you just want to use the comparison in your own class, you could make it a regular static method instead of overriding an operator:

```
public static bool SomeClassEqual(SomeClass a, SomeClass b) { 
  if (a.i == b.i) {
    return true;
  }
  // compare some other members as well
  return false; 
}
```

Usage:

```
if (SomeClassEqual(a, b))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's what I wanted to know. So I guess I will have to write stupid functions to do the comparison. Darn it.

Comment: I think you mean [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx), not `IEquatable<T>`.  The former can be used to compare two objects of a particular type, while the latter is used to compare some other object of a specific type to the object implementing `IEquatable<T>`.  In other words, an equality comparer is not a party to the equality test, while an equatable is.

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, you can't use `return true;` on a `void` method.

Second, overriding operators should be applied to the host class. In your case, inside `SomeClass` rather than inside `TestClass`.

Third, when you implement `==` overriding operator, you should also implement `!=` .

Here is your code, revised and working:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    // Have some other data members as well  
    public int i;

    public static bool operator ==(SomeClass a, SomeClass b)
    {
        if (a.i == b.i)
            return true;
        // compare some other members as well
        return false;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(SomeClass a, SomeClass b)
    {
        return !(a == b);
    }
}

public class TestClass
{

    public bool SomeFunction()
    {
        SomeClass a = new SomeClass();
        SomeClass b = new SomeClass();
        if (a == b) // this is where I am getting compile error
            return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry my bad. This is just a sample code. I will fix it. Thanks!

Comment: Yes that's what I wanted to confirm is it possible to override operator outside the host class?

Comment: Thanks for the updated code. Actually I know that putting those methods inside the actual class would work. What my question actually was was that whether or not it could work if I try to override them outside the host class. But I guess it is not possible as answered by @Guffa. Thanks for the reply anyways.